# Is there a uniform way to discover information about devices?

Tags: devices, udev

**UPD**: Changed question title from `manage devices` to `discover information about devices`

One of the frequent thing I do is look up info about devices on my systems. And I am constantly find myself confused about various different commands on Linux to query available disks, network adapters, graphics cards etc.

For example, if I need to query all disk drives available, I do:

```
ls -la /dev/disk/by-id
```

If I need to query all network cards available, I do:

```
ls -la /sys/class/net
```

Is there any single point to query all device ids by type?

Maybe there was initiative to unify handling of devices info and make it discoverable/accessible, but it failed?

History of the question in order of appearance:

1. [/dev/disk/ lists disks, why /dev/net/ doesn't list network interfaces?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/105402/dev-disk-lists-disks-why-dev-net-doesnt-list-network-interfaces?lq=1)
2. [Why are network interfaces not in /dev like other devices?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/23199/why-are-network-interfaces-not-in-dev-like-other-devices)

Comment: there is now on most linux distro the command `lspci` `lsusb` and so on that allow a nice listing. But I don't thing there anything working everywhere.

Comment: Your main issue is also one of mine: network interfaces not having entries in `/dev`, thus being among the few devices that break the Unix file paradigm. It messes with my Chi, man. (and my OCD)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no single standard or tool to query hardware devices on Linux systems in general. Depending on your host's architecture, and which of its components you must query, and how much detail you need about it, you may need one or more tools specific to that component. However some commands/tools are in wider use and have greater mindshare than others. Following are some--that may or may not be available for your particular host--but are nonetheless Generally Regarded As Useful and widely available from major package managers (though I only link to Debian below):

all-purpose query tools:

- [`hwinfo`](https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=hwinfo). `hwinfo --short` - gives a useful overview of [The Whole Enchilada](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/whole_enchilada), and `info hwinfo` shows many other options for querying specific subsystems in detail.
- [`inxi`](https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=inxi) is part of a larger ["collection of system administration tools"](http://smxi.org/docs/) with similarly general capabilities.

tools for specific subsystems:

- `dmidecode` - processor, memory and motherboard details from BIOS
- `lscpu` - processor details from `/proc/cpuinfo`
- `lspci` - PCI devices, typically graphics cards, audio cards, network cards
- `lsusb` - USB devices in general
- `ls -l /dev/disk/by-{id,label}/` - block devices and their block device files
- `ls -l /sys/class/net/` - network devices and their network interfaces
- `udevinfo` - block devices, if using `udev`

I encourage people to expand this list if some essential tool is missing.

Answer (score 3):

I think you are looking for [hwinfo](http://www.linuxintro.org/wiki/Hwinfo) command.
This command helps you to query disk, network and other hardware information

Comment: I was actually looking for a location on a filesystem where I can query all this info with `ls -la`. I don't dare running `hwinfo` inside my server processes.

Comment: @techtonik Mind you, that not everything has a file representation that can be queried by opening and reading.

Comment: @HermanTorjussen, for instance?

Comment: @techtonik For instance information about the motherboard.

Comment: @HermanTorjussen, why there is a problem to provide `/dev/motherboard/model` and other user level fields?

Comment: @techtonik I never said it was problematic, I just said it isn't necessarily so. You question is a bit vague: are you looking for a specific solution to some specific query, or are you asking why there isn't a general solution to managing devices? Please clarify in your question for future readers.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12068/discussion-between-herman-torjussen-and-techtonik)