# How to query (from the command line) high-level desktop-environment information for system characterization

Tags: bash, command-line, window-manager, desktop-environment, system-information

## background

When asking for help with a software problem, it is usually good to identify not only what versions of that particular code one is running, but also characterize the application's platform. [Querying hardware from CLI can be annoying](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/105714/38638), but fortunately hardware is often not part of one's [etiology](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/aetiology#English) or is standard enough to be irrelevant. Querying the foundations of a Linux host via CLI is relatively straightforward (at least since LSB), so one can script general-purpose bash like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

### Attempt to create a high-level commandline-query for
### basic host configuration information (at least, for that
### part of the platform just above the hardware.

# constants------------------------------------------------------------

### "Marker file" paths for specific distros. TODO: complete the set.

DEBIAN_FILE='/etc/debian_version'

# code-----------------------------------------------------------------

### Absolute basics: kernel, distro

for CMD in \
    'date' \
    'uname -rsv' \
    'lsb_release -ds' \
; do
    echo -e "\$ ${CMD}"
    eval "${CMD}"
done

### Distro details via marker file. TODO: extend to all major distros.
### Feel free to add stanzas for your distro's marker.

if [[ -r "${DEBIAN_FILE}" ]] ; then
    for CMD in \
        "cat ${DEBIAN_FILE}" \
    ; do
        echo -e "\$ ${CMD}"
        eval "${CMD}"
    done
fi

### Other important non-graphical libraries, toolkits, etc.

for CMD in \
    'gcc --version | head -n 1' \
; do
    echo -e "\$ ${CMD}"
    eval "${CMD}"
done
```

This produces output like

```
$ date
Sat Sep 17 14:18:28 MST 2016
$ uname -rsv
Linux 3.16.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.16.7-ckt25-2+deb8u3 (2016-07-02)
$ lsb_release -ds
LMDE 2 Betsy
$ cat /etc/debian_version
8.5
$ gcc --version | head -n 1
gcc (Debian 4.9.2-10) 4.9.2
```

## question

What I don't know is, how to similarly script queries for important information about one's [desktop stack](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/20428/38638)? I know I'm running X, so can do

```
## Dunno why X:
## * throws error on `--version`
## * outputs version info to `stderr`
## * wants to include hostname in 'Current Operating System:' line
$ Xorg -version 2>&1 | grep -ve '^$\|^[[:space:]]\|Current Operating System:'
X.Org X Server 1.16.4
Release Date: 2014-12-20
X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
Build Operating System: Linux 3.16.0-4-amd64 x86_64 Debian
Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/vmlinuz-3.16.0-4-amd64 root=/dev/mapper/LVM2_crypt-root ro nomodeset nouveau.modeset=0
Build Date: 11 February 2015  12:32:02AM
xorg-server 2:1.16.4-1 (http://www.debian.org/support) 
Current version of pixman: 0.32.6

$ x-window-manager --version | head -1
metacity 3.14.3
```

and I (just happen to) know I'm using the [Cinnamon desktop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cinnamon_(software)) and so can do

```
$ cinnamon --version
Cinnamon 3.0.6
```

but I have no idea about how to CLI-query for versions of things like GTK (which I know Cinnamon uses), or how to do similar high-level queries in "Qt world," or what to do for Wayland, or about what other parts of the WM/DE/GUI stack are generally important for problem descriptions. What commands can I use to get this information?