# Change MAC address of network interface on lower level

Tags: linux, networking, mac-address

I know that I can change a network interface's MAC address by bringing the interface down, using a command like `ifconfig eth0 hw ether 00:11:22:33:44:55` or `ip link set eth0 address 00:11:22:33:44:55` and then bringing the interface up again. A command like `ip link show eth0` then confirms that the change was successful.

But I recently discovered the files in `/sys/class/net` (originally from [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/194330) answer): each one is a symbolic link to a directory containing files with information about the interface as documented [here](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/ABI/testing/sysfs-class-net) For example, on my machine, the ethernet interface is `enp3s0` (I have no idea why it has such a strange name), and `/sys/class/net/enp3s0` links to `/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.2/0000:03:00.0/net/enp3s0`.

In this directory, I then found the file `address` which is just a text file containing the MAC address of the interface. But when I attempt to change the address using one of the commands above, the `address` file stays the same, so apparently, the commands do not change the MAC address on the lowest level. It is also not possible to change this file in any manner, not even the superuser has permission to do this.

So now, just out of curiosity: Is it possible to change the MAC address of a network interface on this level?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Background

`/proc` and `/sys` filesystems are just a view of kernel structures, both filesystems reside in memory.  Although both filesystems are writable (well, some of the files in there are writable) it is unwise to assume that they behave the same way as a real filesystems.

Operations that allow you to write into a file inside `/proc` or `/sys` end as hooks and then as function calls.  For example:

```
# echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
```

Does not really write to that file, it calls a userspace kernel function.

If a function is not defined for a certain write you will get:

```
write error: Input/output error
```

That is because it does not make sense to write to that file.  It is not that different from writing to the character device of a USB device that has no driver associated to.  The kernel does not know what to do.

There is no function defined for writes against `/sys/class/net/enp3s0/address`, therefore that is not a viable route to change the MAC address of that interface.

#### Can I change the MAC address without calling `ifconfig` or `ip link set` ?

Yes, you can.

If you look at the code for `iproute2` you will find a lot of argument parsing and [a call to `rtnl_talk`](https://github.com/shemminger/iproute2/blob/master/ip/iplink.c#L547).  It looks as follows (this is from the `ip/iplink.c` file):

```
/* lot of argument parsing and `req` setting */

if (rtnl_talk(&rth, &req.n, 0, 0, NULL, NULL, NULL) < 0)
        exit(2);

return 0;
```

`req.n` in there is the MAC address being passed to `rnetlink` function `rtnl_talk` (`man rnetlink` is relevant here).  If you write a program that perform this call it will fire a system call and update the MAC address.  Yet, then you will be doing exactly the same what `ip link set` does.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, especially the Background part was very interesting.

Answer (score 4):

By changing your MAC address at a higher level, for instance using Network Manager, you are not changing the physical MAC address. You are "spoofing" the system, linking the physical MAC to the one you entered.  The physical MAC address is burned into the NIC when it was produced and cannot be changed without changing the hardware.

Comment: But if you run `ip link set enp3s0 address 00:22:33:44:55:66` and then `cat /sys/class/net/enp3s0/address` the spoofed address appears.  That file reflect the kernel's understanding not the hardware.

Comment: Thank you for your answer as well, the separation between the kernel and the actual hardware is a lot clearer for me now.