# Is it possible to expose TCP tunnel in Linux as special character device?

Tags: linux, networking, pipe, tunneling, character-special-files

Recently I found in QNX documentation that it allows to set up message based IPC between processes on separate physical machines by using serial device (`dev/serX`) and it made me wonder:

Is it possible in Linux to create system-wide special device for TCP/UDP tunnel? Something like `nc` stdin/stdout exposed publicly under /dev/something.

In the end I'd like to be able to write something to such file on one machine and receive it on the other end for example:

```
#machine1:
echo "Hello" > /dev/somedev

#machine2:
cat < /dev/somedev
```

I took a look at `nc` man but I didn't find any option to specify io source/destination other than stdio.

Comment: See [Why are network interfaces not in /dev like other devices?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/23199/why-are-network-interfaces-not-in-dev-like-other-devices) which covers the “why not” part.

Comment: Honorable mention: The tun/tap devices can be created in /dev, but you have to do IP encapsulation on them yourself. Extremely useful for some purposes.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[`socat`](http://www.dest-unreach.org/socat) can do do this and many other things with things resembling "streams"

Something using this basic idea should do it for you:

```
Machine1$ socat tcp-l:54321,reuseaddr,fork pty,link=/tmp/netchardev,waitslave

Machine2$ socat pty,link=/tmp/netchardev,waitslave tcp:machine1:54321
```

(adapted from [Examples Page](http://www.dest-unreach.org/socat/doc/socat-ttyovertcp.txt))

If you want to encrypt, you could use a variation of `ssl-l:54321,reuseaddr,cert=server.pem,cafile=client.crt,fork` on machine1, and something like `ssl:server-host:1443,cert=client.pem,cafile=server.crt` on machine2

(More about [socat ssl](http://www.dest-unreach.org/socat/doc/socat-openssl.txt))

Answer (score 7):

Message-passing needs to be implemented at a higher layer; TCP does not have a notion of a message -- the TCP connections transfer streams of octets.

You can achieve something sort-of like what you request with `nc` and [named pipes](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/lpg/node15.html), see `man mkfifo`; or check `socat` as Alex Stragies indicates.

Without a middle-layer service, the basic problems are (1) that data cannot be written to the network unless there is somebody at the other end listening for it, and (2) that TCP connections are bi-directional.

Because you cannot write data to the network unless somebody is listening for it, you must always start the listener *before* you can send data. (In a message passing system the process handling the messages will provide some sort of buffering.)

Your example can be easily rewritten:

- First start a listener on machine2 (the destination):

  ```
   nc -l 1234 | ...some processing with the received data...
  ```

  In your example, this would be

  ```
   nc -l 1234 | cat
  ```

  This will block and wait for somebody to send some data to port 1234.
- Then you can send some data from machine1 (the source):

  ```
  ...make up some data... | nc machine2 1234
  ```

  In your example, this would be

  ```
   echo "Hello" | nc machine2 1234
  ```

If you want to process the received data in some way and respond you can use the coprocessing facility of the shell. For example, this is a very simple (and very stubborn) web server:

```
#! /bin/bash

while :; do
  coproc ncfd { nc -l 1234; }
  while :; do
    read line <&${ncfd[0]} || break
    line="$(
      echo "$line" |
      LC_ALL=C tr -cd ' -~'
    )"
    echo >&2 "Received: \"$line\""
    if [ "$line" = "" ]; then
      echo >&${ncfd[1]} "HTTP/1.0 200 OK"
      echo >&${ncfd[1]} "Content-Type: text/html"
      echo >&${ncfd[1]} "Connection: close"
      echo >&${ncfd[1]} ""
      echo >&${ncfd[1]} "<title>It works!</title>"
      echo >&${ncfd[1]} "<center><b>It works!</b></center>"
      echo >&${ncfd[1]} "<center>-- $(date +%Y-%m-%d\ %H:%M:%S) --</center>"
      break
    fi
  done
  kill %%
  sleep 0.1
done
```

See how the bi-directional communication is achieved between the main body of the script and the coprocess using the file descriptors in the array `$ncfd`.

Comment: You are right, and I have acknowledged that in the answer. Cannot have a character device without some sort of mediating software.

Comment: Looks like you have a UUOC there.

Comment: @MichaelHampton: That was the example provided by the OP. I suppose that `cat` stands for "some process reading for stdin".

Answer (score 5):

If you simply want to connect two computers using a basic program like nc you can redirect from/to `/dev/tcp/<host>/<port>`.

These are not actual devices but a fiction created by bash, so things like `cat /dev/tcp/foo/19` won't work, but `cat < /dev/tcp/foo/19` will.