# Device "eth0" does not exist

Tags: centos, network-interface, ethernet

i am using centos 7. I am typing the command

> ip addr show eth0

but its reply `Device "eth0" does not exist`.

Comment: just try to use autocompletion, maybe the device names differ from one distro to another.
Another way is looking in /dev/ and searching for network devices
but I think in famous distro it would be ```enp```

Comment: @MiladAlkhamis Are you sure that network devices are under `/dev` location? It seems that’s not possible: [Why are network interfaces not in /dev like other devices?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/23199/why-are-network-interfaces-not-in-dev-like-other-devices) and [Is there a device file in the /dev directory that represents the wireless adapter?](https://superuser.com/questions/564113/is-there-a-device-file-in-the-dev-directory-that-represents-the-wireless-adapte)

Comment: Or maybe that has changed over the years, could you give more details about what network devices can be found in `/dev`? I commented again this because the comments have been moved to the question (but I did it to point to your comment and not to the OP)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In CentOS, network interfaces are named differently. So they aren't called `eth0` or `eth1`, but rather have names like `eno1` or `enp2s0`. ([Source.](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/networking_guide/ch-consistent_network_device_naming))

Run `ip addr` to see how these interfaces are named on your system.

These names are defined in `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-<iface>`. You can change their names if you really wanted to, but I don't recommend it.

Answer (score 0):

RHEL / CentOS 7.x uses **consistent network device naming**. And it might also be called *predictable network interface names*.

in any case the best way I have found to get **eth** naming back is to

- yum remove biosdevname
- edit /etc/default/grub
- append net.ifnames=0 to GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX
- append biosdevname=0 to GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX if you have biosdevname installed
- grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/efi/EFI/centos/grub.cfg {replace centos with rhel}
- reboot
- eth0 and eth1 and so on should now be there instead of the naming syntax that was used.

You do not need to mess with anything under /etc/sysconfig/.

Answer (score 0):

#### For macOS

[@dr](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/462908/302720)'s answer applies to macOS too, but on macOS, they're called `en0`, `en1`, `en2` ....

Running `ifconfig` in the terminal will list them.